Getting ModuleNotFoundError for both 'azureml.pipeline' and azureml.widgets
While trying to import PythonScriptStep and RunDetails using:
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
from azureml.widgets import RunDetails

Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.pipeline'
and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.widgets' errors
I tried manually installing azureml pipeline using:
!pip install azureml-pipeline
Getting various incompatability errors:
ERROR: ray 2.0.0 has requirement click<=8.0.4,>=7.0, but you'll have click 8.1.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ray 2.0.0 has requirement grpcio<=1.43.0,>=1.28.1; python_version < "3.10", but you'll have grpcio 1.54.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pyopenssl 23.0.0 has requirement cryptography<40,>=38.0.0, but you'll have cryptography 42.0.8 which is incompatible.
ERROR: jupyterlab-server 2.23.0 has requirement jinja2>=3.0.3, but you'll have jinja2 2.11.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datasets 2.3.2 has requirement dill<0.3.6, but you'll have dill 0.3.6 which is incompatible.
ERROR: dask-sql 2023.6.0 has requirement pandas>=1.4.0, but you'll have pandas 1.1.5 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-widgets 1.56.0 has requirement azureml-core~=1.56.0, but you'll have azureml-core 1.51.0.post1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-widgets 1.56.0 has requirement azureml-telemetry~=1.56.0, but you'll have azureml-telemetry 1.51.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-inference-server-http 0.8.4 has requirement flask<2.3.0, but you'll have flask 2.3.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azure-cli 2.49.0 has requirement azure-keyvault-keys==4.8.0b2, but you'll have azure-keyvault-keys 4.8.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azure-cli 2.49.0 has requirement azure-mgmt-keyvault==10.2.0, but you'll have azure-mgmt-keyvault 10.2.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azure-cli 2.49.0 has requirement azure-mgmt-resource==22.0.0, but you'll have azure-mgmt-resource 21.1.0b1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azure-cli-core 2.49.0 has requirement msal[broker]==1.20.0, but you'll have msal 1.22.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: autokeras 1.0.16 has requirement tensorflow<=2.5.0,>=2.3.0, but you'll have tensorflow 2.11.0 which is…
Show all (20.4 kB)

Can someone please help me with these errors.

Are you trying this in local vs code or in ml workspace notebook? if you are running this in ml notebook please provide which kernal you using?

@JayashankarGS, I am running it in ml azure workspace notebook, kernel is Python 3.10 - SDK v2

@JayashankarGS, I am learning from a tutorial from Nov 2022, is it due to SDK v1 vs v2 issue ?

Yes. PythonScriptStep and RunDetails are form sdk v1 which is need to be imported from azureml py38 kernel.

If you are working in ml workspace you change the kernel to azureml_py38  which is sdk v1 as shown in below image.

If you want to create the separate environment locally, then create an yml file out this environment using below command in terminal.
conda env export > environment.yml


Next, create separate  conda environment with that yml file using below command.
conda env create -f environment.yml


I hear now the DP100 exam is based on SDK v2, is it possible to do what I am trying to do in v2 please?

yes. but i hope now you are able to import correctly.

Sorry, import what correctly ?

from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
from azureml.widgets import RunDetails
this is working right?

Yes I am able to, but could you please let me know how to use SDK v2 ?

Do I need to use different functions for PythonScriptStep and RunDetails

You need  PythonScriptStep and RunDetails in sdk v2 right?

Instead of python script we have command job in sdk v2 where you execute command like python main.py. here is the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/run-training-script-command-job-azure-machine-learning/

Also the migrate from v1 to v2 you can refer here regarding pipelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-execution-pipeline?view=azureml-api-2. In v2 the pipeline is kind of like components build using yml files and use that for creating pipeline.

Is there a full tutorial you can share with me please to prepare for DP 100 exam.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/credentials/certifications/resources/study-guides/dp-100
